# Keeping GET data over multiple pages without submitting again?

Tags: php, html, get

I have a hangman game where the user can choose one player or two player.

The way it is designed, the game is all on one page and uses post and get variable if statements to display the correct information. Upon first arriving to the page the user has the option of clicking a button which submits via GET either one player or two player.

Then depending on that, and a `if($_GET['numplayers']==1)` type of statement the appropriate content is loaded.

My issue is that for two players, I also have a form submission for one player to choose a word, so it has to be post (so the other player couldn't see it in the url). And then there's the fact that on this second submission I lose the numplayers get variable.

Is there a way I can keep the `$_GET['numplayers']` variable without having to use session variables? I don't want it to stick around that long, my fear being if they move to another page and then back to hangman, but want to play with a different number of players then it will not work.

Comment: you can do this by session/cookie

Comment: @NullPointer Yes, I understand that. However, I want it displayed in the URL bar which I thought was only possible through GET. Thoughts?

Comment: @ZAX, how do you expect to get it in the URL without putting it there yourself?

Comment: @Charles if you use get, the variable and information can be passed in the url bar...

Comment: Nothing says you need to *pay attention* to it though.  If you know the data will be inside the session, use that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use AJAX and avoid form submission and reloading of the page.
- keep the data in the database per game.
- for every game, its players info and state should be in the database. (use a NoSQL preferably)
- when some one arrrives at a game page's unique URL (assign a game id which u will pass in querystring or have clean urls)
- on that page check which player has arrived, if that player is part of he game, let him play.